Why in the Aharonov-Bohm effect the fact that the space is not simply connected leads to a vector potencial circulation different to zero?
I don't understand it, I don't know much about college mathematics, but why does the vector potential have to be constant if there is no hole in space but can have different values if there is a hole in space?

It's not clear what you're talking about. What hole in space? Also, much like adding a constant to all your voltages changes nothing, so does adding a constant vector potential--i.e., gauge invariance. The wonders of the AB effect is that it elevates $\vec A$ from a math bookkeeping device for E and B fields to something that is observable (in a way) along paths where E and B are zero.

This might be helpful - Aharonov–Bohm effect

If there's no solenoid the vector potential has to be equal at both y>0 and y<0, but if there is solenoid they can be different because the topology changes and it's not simply connected anymore. What I don't understand is why this difference in topology changes the vector potential

Vector potential in Bohm-Aharonov experiment and the Bohm-Aharonov phenomenon itself have nothing to do with topology of space, this seems to be just a misunderstanding of some mathematics involving line integrals. Space is Euclidean, and vector potential in it is due to current in the solenoid, no change in topology of space is implied.

This is far from an easy question and I am afraid it would take more than a comment to answer it properly. The answer has to to do with topology.
I recommend you to read "Gauge Fields, Knots & Gravity" from John C. Baez, which present the most pedagogical answer to this in my knowledge (this in chapter 6 p.130).
This has to do with the fact that with a "hole" represented by the solenoid at the center, the space-time is no more simply connected (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space). Intuitively, a (topological) space is simply connected if every loop you can imagine in space can be continuously contracted into to a point. No matter how you think, if there is a hole, a loop surrounding the hole can not be continuously transformed into a point. The path taken by the electron around the solenoid is exactly such a loop which can not be reduced to a point, traducing the fact that the phase difference can not be eliminated.

So since there's no way to contract a loop into a hole, the circulation over that loop can be different than 0? Because if that happened in a simply connected space the vector potential wouldn't be smooth at the point but if there is a hole, since you can't do that there's no worry about whether the vector potential is smooth or not? Am I understanding this right?

But space is simply connected, a current-carrying solenoid does not change anything about that. The solenoid provides electric current distribution, not a hole in spacetime.

In quantum theory, electron does not "take a path around the solenoid". We have line integrals, and circulation integrals, of vector potential, and the closed path can be contracted to a point, because the space is Euclidean, with no holes.

I am not sure if the discussion about the phrase "simply connected region" is valid or not.
Please take what I write here with a grain of salt.
Let us consider the solution for a DC infinitely long solenoid coil.
Let $R$ be the radius of the cylinder and $B_z^0$ be the uniform magnetic flux density inside,
both of them are constants.
The solution of vector potential in cylindrical coordinate is given by,
\begin{equation*}
A_{\theta}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}B_z^0r & \text{if }r<R \\
\frac{1}{2}(B_z^0R)\frac{R}{r} & \text{if }R\leq r
\end{cases} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
And the magnetic flux density is given by
\begin{equation*}
B_z=
\begin{cases}
B_z^0 & \text{if }r<R \\
0 & \text{if }R\leq r
\end{cases} \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
Other components not listed are $0$.
The simple fact is that equations (1) and (2) are solutions of Maxwell's equations for a DC infinitely long solenoid coil.
Outside the coil the vector potential is non-zero, but the magnetic flux density is zero.
Vector potential is a vector quantity, that is, a first-order tensor quantity. Magnetic flux density, on the other hand, is a second-order antisymmetric tensor.
Vector potential, which is a first-order tensor quantity, seems to be a more fundamental physical quantity than a second-order antisymmetric tensor, and I believe it was the AB effect that asserted this.
By the way, equations (1) and (2) simply describe the solution in a simple Euclidean space and have nothing to do with whether the space is simply connected or not.
I think it's a stretch to claim that whether or not the space is simply connected or not is relevant to the solution discussion.
